# Python find first (non-)matching fixed-width word on a large file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, performance, mmap

I will start by describing my problem. I have a binary file (consider it a relatively large file , e.g. 1GiB) consisting of sequences of *8*-bytes. I need to create two fast routines:

1. to search this file for the index of the first *8*-byte sequence equal to `0x0000000000000000`.
2. to search this file for the index of the first *8*-byte sequence different from `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Note that both routines need to search **aligned** sequences, meaning that the match should start at the beginning of a sequence. I can change the file format (as I did below), but I need it to be able to represent a giant list of integers. Furthermore, this file will be accessed concurrently (read / update)  from lots of scripts (lets say, about 100), but I'm using `fcntl.flock` to avoid a disaster.

So far, I added a byte separator (`\xAA`) **before** every *8*-byte sequence to make it easier to search without clashes. Hence, I consider the first problem solved, since I can use `mmap.find` to search for the first occurence of `0xAA0000000000000000`, but I'm having problems to solve the second.

Currently, to solve the second problem, I'm using the regex below applied to `mmap`, but I don't know if and how I can improve it further (I broke it into multiple lines to make it easier to read).

```
b"\xaa(?:" \
b"[^\xff].......|" \
b".[^\xff]......|" \
b"..[^\xff].....|" \
b"...[^\xff]....|" \
b"....[^\xff]...|" \
b".....[^\xff]..|" \
b"......[^\xff].|" \
b".......[^\xff])"
```

To test the performance of both methods, I made the stress test below. It creates a ~ 1GiB file containing the worst case for each problem, i.e., where the search needs to fully parse each sequence, and tries to execute the solutions I proposed above.

```
import re
import mmap
import time

zeros = b"\xaa" + (b"\x00" * 8)
ones = b"\xaa" + (b"\xff" * 8)

regex = b"\xaa(?:" \
        b"[^\xff].......|" \
        b".[^\xff]......|" \
        b"..[^\xff].....|" \
        b"...[^\xff]....|" \
        b"....[^\xff]...|" \
        b".....[^\xff]..|" \
        b"......[^\xff].|" \
        b".......[^\xff])"

reg = re.compile(regex)

file = open("1gib", "wb")
file.write(ones * 128 * 1024 * 1024)
file.close()

file = open("1gib", "rb+")
mem = mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0)

start = time.time()
reg.search(mem)
print(time.time() - start) # 17.609468460083008

mem.close()
file.close()

file = open("1gib", "wb")
file.write((zeros[ : -1 ] + b"\xff") * 128 * 1024 * 1024)
file.close()

file = open("1gib", "rb+")
mem = mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0)

start = time.time()
mem.find(zeros)
print(time.time() - start) # 1.539649248123169

mem.close()
file.close()
```

One can see from the runtimes that the `find` strategy is about 11.5 times faster than the regex one. How can I improve the second strategy to be as fast as the first?

Note that I am happy with the first strategy performance, but if you have any suggestions of improvements, I'm open to it :)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try this:   regex=b"\xaa(?!\xff{8}).{8}"

Comment: @kantal time = 4.234770774841309, nice! Do you know why this format is better than the one I used? I thought that this would cause a problem with backtracking.

Comment: Have you considered searching for consecutive matches to `0xAAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, and then the next sequence after would be a non-match, or end of string? That is- `re.compile(b"(\xaa"+b"\xff"*8+b")*").search(mem).end()`. If that equals `len(mem)`, no match is found. If it doesn't, then that's the start of your target sequence. If no matches are found, the first element is your target sequence.

Comment: Actually you would need to use `match` instead of `search` in my above code, so that it won't skip over the first element if its not `0xAAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @Marco I think the same,there are actually eight expressions in your regexp, resulting in eight program branching, too. But i'm not an expert, just feel that way:-)

Comment: @DillonDavis since the file is too big, this expression took all my memory and froze my computer, hence I had to kill the process.